# What is Google Dictionary?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Google Dictionary only exist in the form of a [Google Chrome addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-dictionary-by-goog/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja?hl=en). Does the addon use [Google Translate's](https://translate.google.com/) definitions?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question is asking about a specific extension but general culture and questions about installable software are off-topic. On the other hand, questions about extensions might be on-topic when they are related to using a web application, not about how they work. The information about the extension can be found on the respective extension page listing linked in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was initially a separate service that spun out of Google Translate but is now incorporated into Google Search. To invoke it, use the `define` keyword with the term you want to get a definition of. Example:

[define dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20dictionary)

The Chrome extension merely allows you to highlight words and get a pop-up with Google's dictionary definition without going to Google Search separately.

More information: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Dictionary)

Comment: Not all the questions should be answered. Ref. [answer].